# How to use typescript in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: typescript

I want to know how to use and install typescript in visual studio 2012.

I already tried nuget package manager but, when I run this command:

```
uget package manager Install-Package Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler -Version 2.9.2
```

... it gives me this error:

> InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: What did you do to get that error?

Comment: i have run this command to nuget package manager Install-Package Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler -Version 2.9.2